# Como verificar se as propriedades do objeto window são nativas?

Tags: javascript, dom, navegador-de-internet

Estou utilizando *shim* que modifica vários das propriedades no objeto window dos browsers.

Neste momento preciso validar se uma das propriedades especificas é nativa ou um shim. Pois os shim podem modificar a propriedade nativa.

Por exemplo:

```
(function () {
  var native = window.alert;
  window.alert = function (): {
    /* faz alguma coisa */
    console.log(arguments);
    return native.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

No exemplo podemos ver que ele não muda a funcionalidade do `alert` aplicando o original ao final, porém esse `alert` não é mais o original em outro trecho de código eu gostaria de saber se esse método é o original ou um modificado.

O `alert` foi usado só como fins de exemplo do problema.

Sem modificar o "shim" que não expõe mais o `alert` nativo, como acessar o `alert` nativo para comparar com o modificado e saber que a função no `window` não é a nativa?

Comment: Caso não esteja implementado, ele retorna false quando usando em um if().

Comment: @2madera não foi isso que eu perguntei, `alert` vai retornar verdadeiro sendo ele modificado ou nativo. Quero saber se ele é nativo ou não. Se ele existe no objeto `window` é outra coisa bem simples de resolver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma função nativa irá retornar `function () { [native code] }` ao ser convertida para string.

```
var nativa = typeof funcao === 'function ' && funcao.toString().indexOf('[native code]') !== -1
```

Por outro lado isso não funciona caso a função `Function.prototype.toString` tenha sido modificada.

Você pode ter acesso a funções do javascript nativas usando outra janela (um iframe ou um popup) e ainda compará-las:

```
function retrieveNative(native) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.head.appendChild(iframe);
  var retrieved = iframe.contentWindow[native];
  document.head.removeChild(iframe);
  return retrieved;
}
var alertNativo = retrieveNative('alert');
```

Observação:
O correto é colocar no `body` o `iframe`, porém se o mesmo não foi carregado ainda, vai gerar uma exceção, colocando no `head` não vai carregar o `iframe` porém ele vai fornecer acesso ao `window` que é o objetivo neste caso.

Créditos ao @bfavaretto pela alteração nos comentários.

Comment: +1, esse hack do iframe é a única solução em certos casos.

Comment: +1 eu usei esse hack do `iframe` também, mas agora... estou tendo problema pois preciso fazer essa validação antes dele carregar do DOM, então não da pra fazer `appendChild` no `body`.

Comment: @Gabriel Você pode tentar um appendChild no head. Seria html inválido, mas se funcionar...

Comment: Uma observação importante sobre esse método: tudo o que vem do outro frame é completamente independente do que está no frame pai. Portanto se você pegar um construtor, como em `var obj = retrieveNative('Object')`, e comparar com o nativo, verá que são diferentes (`obj.prototype != Object.prototype`)

Comment: @bfavaretto muito boa cara funcionou e resolveu cara!!! Tenho vontade de dar accept pros dois, pois foi esforço em comum, mas como faze-lo? hehe Tem como dar accept nessa questão e mesmo assim te gratificar cara?

Comment: Não se preocupe, @GabrielGartz. Aceita a solução do Gustavo, é mais completa (Gustavo: se quiser adicionar minha sugestão no corpo da resposta, fique à vontade).

Comment: Fica expressa minha gratidão pela sua ideia de usar o `head` pois funcionou e resolveu o caso para todos os browsers agora, uma vez que posso comparar por string se é nativo e no iframe se ele existe no `window` padrão.

Comment: Essa função eu peguei dos meus favoritos, que tinha pego uma questão do SOEN. Podem editar a questão, ainda mais se encontrarem a fonte da função.

Comment: Achei a fonte, não pensei que seria tão fácil: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108140/1850091

Comment: Já tem muitos comentários, vamos deixar como está: se formos preocupar muito com isso teremos que fazer igual o Google Analytics, pois o `document.head` pode não funcionar caso seja `<=IE8`.

Answer (score 7):

Não sei o quanto isto seria compatível com todos os browsers, mas se você converter a função para string, verá o código-fonte no caso das funções não-nativas, e uma string contendo `[native code]` nas nativas. Por exemplo, no caso da sua variável `native` (testado no console do Chrome):

```
native.toString(); // function alert() { [native code] }
```

Com base nisso, pode-se criar uma função para verificar isso:

```
function nativa(fn) {
    return typeof fn == 'function' && fn.toString().indexOf('[native code]') > -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 Cara eu posso usar essa solução no meu caso muito exclusivamente por causa de uma falha de implementação do shim que to tentando detectar, mas no IE não vai funcionar e se resolverem a dependência corretamente em uma futura versão vai acabar quebrando. O ideal era conseguir acessar o método original mesmo.

Comment: Eu foquei na pergunta do título e deixei passar o mais importante, a última frase. A solução é o que o Gustavo Rodrigues postou.

Answer (score 4):

Para restaurar uma função nativa, podemos usar o `delete`. Exemplo:

```js
delete window.alert;
```

Então, aplicando isso numa função que deleta e restaura o valor inicial, podemos verificar se a função é nativa sem o hack do `iframe`:

```js
function isNative(object, name) {
    var aux = object[name]; //salva o valor
    delete object[name]; //apaga a função
    var result = object[name] == aux; //se continuar a mesma é porque é nativa
    object[name] = aux; //restaura a anterior, caso não seja a nativa
    return result;
}
```

Teste:

```js
console.log(window.alert, isNative(window, 'alert'));
window.alert = function() { }
console.log(window.alert, isNative(window, 'alert'));
delete window.alert;
console.log(window.alert, isNative(window, 'alert'));
```

Saída:

> True
>
> False
>
> True

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/A48x6/)

**Nota:** está técnica não funciona em alguns navegadores caso a função tenha sido definida  com a função [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) e o parâmetro `writable : false`. Veja o [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/A48x6/1/) de teste. No Chrome não houve problemas, mas no Firefox a função retornou `true` quando deveria ser `false`.

**Nota 2:** também não funciona se a definição da função for feito diretamente no escopo global, por exemplo:

```js
function alert() { ... }
```

Comment: Cara, maneira essa ideia, vou testar, mas acho que até o momento de fato é a melhor de todas.

Comment: Boa mesmo. Só deve falhar se o shim tiver sido FDP o suficiente para sobrescrever a função com [[Configurable]]  `false`. Isso acontece se ele declarar `function alert(){}` em vez de `window.alert = ...`, ou usando `Object.defineProperty` para setar o atributo explicitamente.

Comment: @GabrielGartz Certo, faça o teste. Não sei se pode ter algum efeito colateral ou algum caso em que não funcione. Se alguém souber me informe!

Comment: @bfavaretto No Chrome [funcionou](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/A48x6/1/), pois ele deve ter ignorado o `writable`. No firefox não. :(

Comment: Você precisa definir o `configurable` para impedir o `delete`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acabei de ver!

Comment: Tipo pro meu caso os shim do Polymer não usam `defineProperty` então funcionou, no Webkit, Mozilla e Opera, definitivamente é usa solução mais leve que as anteriores, porém a do @GustavoRodrigues não da pra ser enganada eu acredito...

Comment: @GabrielGartz Não é só defineProperty, `function alert(){}` já impede um delete (a propriedade é criada como não-configurável).

Comment: É que a função do @utluiz não prevê mas eu testo 2 coisas, se após o delete elas são iguais e se após o delete ela ainda existe no `window`. No caso de `alert` são diferentes mas existe nativa, no caso de `HTMLTemplateElement` não existe nativa após o delete no Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é fazer um "backup" da janela antes de rodar o seu shim. Depois disso você pode comparar os valores das funções com o valor antigo do backup pra ver se houve uma alteração.

```
//Coloque esse código em uma tag <script> anterior à tag <script> com o shim.
var window_backup = {}
for(var k in window){
    window_backup[k] = window[k];
}

function is_native(key){
   return window[key] === window_backup[key];
}
```

A principal vantagem dessa abordagem é que você não depende de detalhes de implementação como o resultado da função toString e não precisa mexer no objeto window depois que rodar o shim.

Comment: +1 Essa é legal também, mas obriga que seja instanciada antes dos shim, o que limita bastante a possibilidade de uso. Obrigado pela contribuição.